# Every 50px put a different height to an element

Tags: javascript

I am working on an application where there is a live video in the view and I need to set the CSS part in the JavaScript code.

I don't need any type of solution in CSS, please.

I was doing something like this

```
var playerMsgs =  document.getElementById('player-msgs');

if (windowHeight >= 750 && windowHeight <= 800) {
  playerMsgs.style.height = '40%';
} else if (windowHeight >= 801 && windowWidth >= 850) {
  playerMsgs.style.height = '45%';
} ... // and son
```

which I don't feel comfortable because I guess I can do a proper code in order to do it programatically, as you can see, every `50px` the percentage change 5%, the minor height my app is supporting is `750px`, so from `750px` the percentage is 40% as you see in the code.

If the window size presents a height of `750px` the height should be `40%` and the same percentage until the next `50px`, so `750px && 800px` should present `height` of `40%`, if the height now is `801px` then the new `height` should be set to `45%` and so on... so, what is the best way to do that ?

TLDR

Increment 5% of height on every 50px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Math is your friend:

```
var hdiff = windowHeight - 750;

if (hdiff >= 0)
{
  var pct = Math.floor((hdiff / 10) + 40);
  playerMsgs.style.height = pct + "%";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Might require some validations upfront, but basically, the formula could be:

```
var newHeight = (Math.floor((windowHeight - 750) / 50) * 5 + 40) + '%';
playerMsgs.style.height = newHeight;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it with mathematical operations.

```
var difference = WindowHeight - 750;
var extra = Math.floor(difference/50)
var percent = 40 + extra*5;
```